# XSLT math:min() on list does not work while sorting does

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, javax.xml

I want to get the code for the `medias` node with the lowest index. The source XML looks similar to this:

```
<item>
    <medias>
        <index>999997</index>
        <code>0001</code>
    </medias>
    <medias>
        <index>1</index>
        <code>0002</code>
    </medias>
    <medias>
        <index>999998</index>
        <code>0003</code>
    </medias>
    <medias>
        <index>999999</index>
        <code>0004</code>
    </medias>
</item>
```

In my XSLT I tried this:

```
<xsl:variable name="minIndex" select="math:min(item/medias/index)" />
<xsl:value-of select="item/medias[index=$minIndex]/code" />
```

But for some reason, the `minIndex` variable does not get the lowest value of all values, but simply the value of the first node, in this case `999997`.

When sorting the nodes though, the values are ordered correctly:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item/medias">
    <xsl:sort select="index" />
    <xsl:value-of select="." /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This outputs:

```
1,999997,999998,999999
```

Is there something else I have to take care for when using `math:min`? I also tried adding `/text()` to the end of my selection (after `index`), but that didn't work either.

**EDIT:** I'm constructing my XSL transformer in Java using simply this code and giving it the XSLT file as the source:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsltSource);
```

Comment: How is the namespace prefix `math` declared? It suggests you are using an extension function. However you've tagged this XSLT 2.0, but and `min` is an built-in XPath 2.0 function, so you can just do `<xsl:variable name="minIndex" select="min(item/medias/index)" />`

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSF where Tim's suggestion works fine.

Comment: It also seems to work fine when using the Exslt math extension. See http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVH. Can you say exactly what XSLT processor you are using? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the missing information in the question. The `math` namespace seems to be provided by Java; simply using `min` without a prefix tells me that this function does not exist :(

Comment: Can you post a minimal but complete stylesheet? Does using `<xsl:value-of select="math:lowest(/item/medias/index)/../code"/>` work better?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried using the same as in Tim's example. `lowest` seems to do the same for me!

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsq uses Xalan and the suggested `math:lowest` from EXSLT and seems to do the job. So which Java version do you use where the code does not work? I guess you are better off switching to Saxon 9 and XSLT 2.0 if you are running into a bug in the default transformer and need to install/integrate a different transformer anyway.

Comment: @MartinHonnen when explicitly adding the namespace `xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"` to my transformation file it works! Curious why it doesn't throw an error otherwise.. oO

Comment: @maxdev Perhaps you're not capturing the error.

Answer (score 0):

When explicitly specifying the namespace to use the EXSLT extensions, both `math:min` and `math:lowest` do the job.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math">
                                       ...
```

Comment: It only does the job if the XSLT processor supports those extension functions. And since you're obviously using an XSLT 1.0 processor, you should not be declaring `version="2.0"`.

Answer (score 0):

`math:min(...)` is used e.g. in Java (precisely - `math.min(...)`).

Write just `min(...)`.

I tried this and got the proper result.

Comment: `math:min()` is not in Java, it's an EXSLT extension function. And you can only use `min()` if you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor - which OP is obviously not.